# Cannot trigger Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

i have following code, i am unable to load a Dialog Box

```
function CreateDialog(data){
                 alert('Hello');
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "OK": function() {
                            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                            jQuery.append('<table><tr>');
                            jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                jQuery.append("<td>"+value+"</td>");
                            });
                            jQuery.append('</tr></table>')
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                    close: function() {
                        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    }
                });}
```

now i can alert but i cannot trigger Dialog, i am also not getting any error. I am linking my libraries as follows.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to open your dialog from? Have you tried `$("#dialog-form").dialog('open');`? You are just creating the dialog,  but as [autoOpen](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen) is set to false, you need to manually open it.

Comment: Since `autoOpen: false`, what triggers the dialog?

Comment: i dont know what is the optimal approach i just followed the snippet at Jquery UI site

Comment: Remove `autoOpen:false` and you'll be happy!

Comment: @ojovirtual:thx it worked, i will accept the 1st amswer given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your dialog set to autoOpen: false which means you have to open it yourself:

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open

Comment: so you say that i have to change it to true?

Comment: it's `.dialog("open")` by the way. you link the api, but don't even use it right :P

Comment: @noobie-php if you set autoOpen to true the dialog is opened as soon as you create it. Otherwise you have to open it after.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line

`autoOpen: false,`

Comment: yes i dont wanna open it right away!, any solution for that?

Comment: your solution is @mcbex's answer then. you want to explicitely open it some other time using `$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");`

Comment: @noobie-php With my answer it'll only open when you call CreateDialog(data); method.